# Vue bind emit data to table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, binding, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to write my first Vue app, which will allow a CSV upload and display the data in a table. I can upload the file and render the contents to the console, and parse the CSV with Papa. I cannot seem to bind the data from the file to a table, though. I started [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/file-reader-component/)  and added Papa parsing for CSV handling.

Here is the pertinent code:

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

  /* eslint-disable no-new */
  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Upload.vue Component

```
<template>
    <h1>Upload CSV</h1>
    <input type='file' @change='loadTextFromFile'>
</template>

<script>
// csv parsing
import Papa from 'papaparse'

export default {
  methods: {
    loadTextFromFile (event) {
      if (!event.target.files[0]) {
        alert('Upload a file.')
      } else {
        let file = event.target.files[0]
        if (file) {
          let reader = new FileReader()
          let config = {
            delimiter: ',',
            newline: '',
            quoteChar: '"',
            escapeChar: '"',
            header: false,
            trimHeaders: false
          }
          // reader.onload = e => this.$emit('load', e.target.result)
          reader.onload = e => this.$emit('load', Papa.parse(event.target.result, config))
          // trace what was emitted
          reader.onload = function (event) {
            let results = Papa.parse(event.target.result, config)
            console.log('PAPA RESULT: ', results.data)
            console.log('ROWS:', event.target.result)
          }
          reader.readAsText(file)
        } else {
          alert('Please select a file to upload.')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>My CSV Handler</h1>
    <br>
    <upload @load="items = $event"></upload>
    <br>
    <table>
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!-- eslint-disable-next-line -->
        <tr v-for="row in items">
              <td>{{ row }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Upload from './components/Upload'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ({ items: [] }),
  components: {
    Upload
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

If I emit the raw `e.target.result` and change 'items' to 'text' everywhere in App.vue, I can successfully render the text data to a text-area just like the tutorial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into limitations of array reactivity. Have a look at the docs explaining the [caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely.

[Source](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)

Here's a quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/215437/) showing how to use `splice` to replace the items array in a way such that it will be reactive to updates.